# Получить две записи в codeignither

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Есть запрос

```
$this->db->where('id_sponsor',$id_sponsor);
$query=$this->db->get('a_plan_1_stage');
return $query->result_array();
```

Как получить только две записи?

Comment: В самом запросе указать `LIMIT 2` не пробовали? Ну и перемещение по результату $query->first_row(), $query->last_row(), $query->next_row(), $query->previous_row().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('id_sponsor',$id_sponsor);
$query=$this->db->get('a_plan_1_stage', 2);
return $query->result_array();
```

И так можно

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('a_plan_1_stage', array('id_sponsor' => $id_sponsor), 2);
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

```
$this->db->where('id_sponsor',$id_sponsor)->limit(2);
$query=$this->db->get('a_plan_1_stage');
return $query->result_array();
```